# Deserialize non existing element in json to meaningful value using other existing element?

Tags: java, json, gson

Suppose I have following json :

> { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" }

Now if I deserialize it to User POJO, which is;

```
public class User {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String fullName;

    //getters setters constructors..
}
```

So I will get following values:

> [firstName=John, lastName=Dow, fullName=null]

Note fullName is null as there is no such element in json.
But what I want is :

> [firstName=null, lastName=null, fullName=John Doe]

How can I achieve this. I am using gson library. In adapters we can not get the values of other fields. Also as there is no `fullname` in original json, how can i mention it in adapters?

Comment: Do firstName and lastName need to be null?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html).   The key idea is to grab a delegate type adapter, use it to do the deserialization, then apply your desired initializations.

```
public class UserTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
  @Override
  public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
    if (typeToken.getType() != User.class) {
      return null;
    }
    return (TypeAdapter<T>) UserAdapter(gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, TypeToken.get(User.class)));
  }

  private  TypeAdapter<User> UserAdapter (final TypeAdapter<User> delegateAdapter) {
    return new TypeAdapter<User>() {

      @Override
      public void write(JsonWriter out, User value) throws IOException {
        delegateAdapter.write(out, value);
      }

      @Override
      public User read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        User user = delegateAdapter.read(in);
        // Post deserialization initialization
        user.fullName = user.firstName + " " + user.lastName;
        return user;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

create your gson with --

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
      .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new UserTypeAdapterFactory())
      .create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will have to create a getter and setter for `fullname` and as you are serializing JSON it to User POJO using gson. Also according to your JSON your POJO will have these values :

> [firstName=John, lastName=Dow, fullName=null]

so in order to get fullName, you should have definition of `getter` and `setter` like this :

```
public String getFullName() {
   return  firstName+" "+lastName;
}

 public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}
```

Comment: The setFullName method should contain logic to split the input to firstName and lastName rather than using a new variable. Or where is he suppose to use that?

Comment: as you see in the question he want the `fullName` to be filled and `firstName`, `lastName` to be null.

Comment: But then I can not se how your solution is going to work since you return firstName + lastName in getFullName().

Comment: I get the point in your answer. Though it solves the problem, I personally would prefer that fullName gets initialize and it get initialize at the time of deserialization itself.

Answer (score 0):

As `fullName` is a derived value, could you not simply modify your setters for `firstName`/`lastName` to calculate it? As they are called during deserialization, you should end up with a properly calculated `fullName` value.

This won't set `firstName` and `lastName` to null, but is that really relevant?

ex:

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName) { 
    this.firstName = firstname; 
    this.fullName = this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.fullName = this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
}
```

Comment: This would be my solution I think.

Comment: This would definately solve the issue, but I was hoping for something like [mRender](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/17383/mrender-function-get-data-from-another-column)   attribute function you get in Datatables where you can access any of the other elements. This example is easy one, just consider what if fullName depends on 5-10 variables then it will be real pain to change setter methods.

Comment: There may be. I have very little experience with gson. For a larger example, I'd definitely agree that this is not efficient and there is likely a better solution.